# Put brackets between numbers

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to edit a txt file by putting between parenthesis only the numbers that represent years. I managed to put parenthesis on all numbers but i can't see how to choose only the numbers that represent years.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When do you know that you have hit a year? If it is just a 4-digit number, you can find it as:

```
[0-9]{4}
```

And then do as you are doing right now with the `.sub()`.

Alternatively, and **better** (at least judging from your screenshot), if a year is anything after the author name and before the `-`, you can use this pattern:

```
(?<=\.\s)[0-9]{4}(?=\s-)
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=\.\s)  // if preceeded by a dot and space
[0-9]{4}   // match 4 numbers
(?=\s-)    // if followed by a space and -
```